# Retaining variables in dcast in R

Tags: r

I am using the `dcast` function in R to turn a long-format dataset into a wide-format dataset. I have an `ID` number, a categorical variable (`CAT`), and a continuous variable (`AMT`). However, I also have a variable `SEX`, which is the same for all rows of a given `ID` number. This code works to create the wide-format dataset, but I lose `SEX`. How can I retain it?

```
PC1cast <- dcast(PC1, ID~CAT, value.var='AMT', fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If I add `SEX` to the `ID~CAT` line, it gives me `SEX-CAT` combinations. I want `SEX` to just be one value for each row.

Sample data:

```
ID CAT AMT SEX 
1  A   46  Female 
1  B   22  Female 
1  C   31  Female 
2  A   17  Male 
2  B   25  Male 
2  C   44  Male
```

Comment: Please don't cross post.

Comment: I think the linked question should be a duplicate of this, since this question is more complete with sample data

Comment: @RichardScriven, True, I retract my vote here.

Answer (score 2):

For that, you need to add `SEX` to the `ID` side of your formula:

```
dcast(PC1, ID + SEX~CAT, value.var='AMT', fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
# results in:

  ID    SEX  A  B  C
1  1 Female 46 22 31
2  2   Male 17 25 44
```

Things on the left hand side of the formula are kept as-is, things on the right-hand side are cast.

Answer (score 1):

I added some extra data lines to clarify some parts of this.  But the gist is that you just need to put `SEX` on the left hand side (i.e., of `~`):

```
PC2 <- read.table(text="ID CAT AMT SEX 
1  A   46  Female 
1  B   22  Female 
1  C   31  Female 
2  A   17  Male 
2  B   25  Male 
2  C   44  Male
3  A   47  Female 
3  B   27  Female 
3  C   37  Female 
4  A   17  Male 
4  A   17  Male 
4  B   22  Male 
4  B   NA  Male 
4  C   44  Male", header=T)

library(reshape2)
PC1cast2 <- dcast(PC2, ID+SEX~CAT, value.var='AMT', fun.aggregate=sum, 
                  na.rm=TRUE)
PC1cast2
#   ID    SEX  A  B  C
# 1  1 Female 46 22 31
# 2  2   Male 17 25 44
# 3  3 Female 47 27 37
# 4  4   Male 34 22 44
```

In your example data, you only have one instance of each combination and no `NA`s, so the `fun.aggregate=sum, na.rm=TRUE` doesn't do anything.  When some are duplicated (e.g., there are two `4 A`s and two `4 B`s), the values are summed, but the `NA`s are dropped first.  Make sure that is what you want.